# Use Lambda expressions and Butterknife

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lambda, butterknife

I tried to use Lambda expressions in my code and I got this error : *lambda expressions are not supported at this language level*

I just search for it on SO and found a solution adding this to gradle file :

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

defaultConfig {
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
```

Then I got a new error : *Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.*

Searched on SO again and found this is because I can't use jack and apt at the same time... so I remove apt deleting those lines :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        ...
    }
```

And got a new error because ButterKnife needs apt...

So how use Lambda and Butterknife in the same project ?

Comment: Butterknife 8.5 doesn't need to setup the `apt`. The recent setup only need :`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use ***annotation processor*** for Butter-knife library in the `build.gradle`

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

**Full Gradle Looks like:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   ....
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
   .....
}}
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
......

android{
.....
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
}
dependencies {
    ..........
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
 }
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't use **jackOption = Enabled**

Comment: it says me to enable Jack : *Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.*

Comment: I tried to open my project with the last Android Studio preview who normally support Java 8 but have the same problem.

Comment: Or try to enable `jackOptions {   enabled true   }`

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, I put this `apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` in the wrong file. It works, thank you.